# Retain summands in an expression that match a given rule

Tags: pattern-matching

Suppose we have the following expression

```
A[j_] := Subscript[A, j]
EXPR=A[1]^2*A[2] + A[1]^4*A[3] + A[2]^2
```

As stated in the title, I am struggling to retain some summands in `EXPR`, in particular the ones for which the sum of the product of the subscript and the power in each term is equal to some integer `c`. For instance, how to get all those terms that satisfy this rule with $c=4$? The correct answer is

```
A[1]^2*A[2] + A[2]^2
```

as in the first term we have $1\cdot 2+2\cdot 1=4$, whereas in the second one $2\cdot 2=4$

Answer (score 2):

```
Pick[EXPR, EXPR /. {Plus -> List, Times -> Plus, Subscript -> (#2 &), Power -> Times}, 4] 

% // TeXForm
```

> $ A_2 A_1^2+A_2^2$

or

```
Select[EXPR, 4 == # /. { Times -> Plus, Subscript -> (#2 &), Power -> Times} &] // TeXForm
```

> $A_2 A_1^2+A_2^2$

Comment: Thanks! Your proposal is partially right in that I looked at the outcome of EXPR /. Plus -> List /. Power[Subscript[A, w_], b_.] :> Times[w, b] and the result is {4,4,12}: 12 is wrong in that the term A[1]^4*A[3] should be "processed" as 1*4+3. This in turn implies that the correct answer your code gave is due because of a lucky structure of the terms involved. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Bounded, i think `EXPR /. {Plus -> List, Times -> Plus, Subscript -> (#2 &), 
  Power -> Times }` fixes the problem.